# How do I make my function anonymous in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

In the code below I firstly try to print the 'normal' way.  Secondly I try to anonymize my function and assign it to a variable which I then print. In Chrome this now proceeds to print the source code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function sumSq() {
    var  sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        sum+=i*i;
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(sumSq());

var mySum = function() {
    var  sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        sum+=i*i;
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(mySum);
```

Comment: Well you didn't call the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `mySum` using `()`:

```
console.log(mySum());
```

Functions are objects, so when you call

```
console.log(mySum);
```

JS calls toString on the mySum object (which mySum inherits from the Object prototype). That's why the source gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

Function should be called as `mySum()`

Apart from this, both ways do the same.

Comment: "Apart from this"? This is _the way_ in which they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySum = function() {
    var  sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        sum+=i*i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

is just the same with:

```
function mySum() {
    var  sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        sum+=i*i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And call it `console.log(mySum());`